# how to give dynamic nature to my jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp

Question is pretty lame I know. And the answer is pretty simple - AJAX (I think, I'm not sure). 
But before proceeding further, I would like to know if there's a better way.

My problem:

I have a web application, that takes in one statement from the user, and then in response to it,sends back another statement. The whole process goes on like this. 
So how can I give a dynamic nature to my JSP then? If I keep reloading the JSP, my old responses will get deleted. So, that's not how it works.

I could use `RequestDispatcher` 's `include()` method. I find that as one solution. So, I can keep including the new pages onto my old JSPs. But again, I think this will have a limitation. Haven't tested it yet though.

Is there a better way around?

Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in love with AJAX consuming Restful Webservices so that is what I would suggest. In addition, if I understand you correctly, I don't think `include()` will help you in this scenario unless you manage to keep streamming your responses in 1 open connection which isn't really ideal in most Web page scenarios.